# Table Partitioning Using created time for each row

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

I am using SQL Server. And I am looking for a solution to partition table based on the `created_time` column for each row.

For example: when `created_time = 2019-12-01` (`yyyy-MM-dd`) my partition key should be `yyyy * 100 + MM` i.e. 201912.

Is there a way to achieve this right at the moment a row is inserted and without adding an extra column in the table (without storing the partition key in the table itself)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to partition based on month you should create a partition function using datetime values and just supply month boundaries. I don't see what value this integer scheme gives you, especially as you don't even want the value stored?

Comment: @marc_s sorry for the confusion, ```2019 (YYYY) * 100 + MM = 201912```

Comment: There's no confusion.  The way to do this in SQL Server is to partition RANGE RIGHT on created_time, and insert partition boundaries for the beginning of each month.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks! How do I do it for next 10 years? I can create a partition function for 120 months using a procedure. How do I create files for those 120 months, will it require manual intervention?

Comment: You don't need separate files for each partition, and you shouldn't without a good reason.  And you can pre-create all the partitions, or run a job every year or so to add new partitions.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft cool, I'll create a partition scheme which writes to only one filegroup. I have created partitions already using TSQL. Thanks!